# How do I import functions from one CoffeeScript file to another?

Tags: function, methods, import, coffeescript

I have two different files both in CoffeeScript and I'd like to access a function from one file in the other. Am I able to import a function from one file into another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same as in Javascript. You can use the commonjs `require` syntax, or if you use a preprocessor like babel you can use modules via the `import` / `export` syntax

### Require

You can export an object containing whatever you like, and use it in another file. Easiest explained with an example:

first.coffee

```
a = (x) ->
  console.log "file first, function a, argument #{x}"

b = 3.1415

module.exports = 
  a: a
  b: b
```

second.coffee:

```
first = require './first'

first.a 'test'
console.log "b: #{first.b}"
```

### Modules

From the [documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#modules)

> ES2015 modules are supported in CoffeeScript, with very similar import and export syntax:
>
> ```
> import './local-file.coffee'
> import 'coffeescript'
>
> import _ from 'underscore'
> import * as underscore from 'underscore'
>
> import { now } from 'underscore'
> import { now as currentTimestamp } from 'underscore'
> ```

You will need to transpile with babel, as import/export isn't supported by default in Node / browsers. A popular example is webpack. Here is an [official example](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/coffee-loader/#coffeescript-and-babel)

> You'll need to install @babel/core and @babel/preset-env and then create a configuration file:
>
> ```
> npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env
> echo '{ "presets": ["@babel/env"] }' > .babelrc
> ```
>
> webpack.config.js
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   module: {
>     rules: [
>       {
>         test: /\.coffee$/,
>         loader: 'coffee-loader',
>         options: {
>           transpile: {
>             presets: ['@babel/env'],
>           },
>         },
>       },
>     ],
>   },
> };
> ```